# MySQL : Access Denied for user

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I have installed **mysql** in my ubuntu 16.10. When I write

```
mysql -v
```

Then It gets error

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rishi'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I have googled a lot to solve my problem. but i couldn't get any solution for the same.

Any help would be same.

Thank You.

Comment: May be useful https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset, did you try this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One Solution that I have got is,

You can download this installer **xampp-linux-x64-7.0.13-1-installer.run** and run it using

```
sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.0.13-1-installer.run
```

This will install your **xampp** , **mysql** and other necessary dependencies.

then run this command in your terminal to stop **mysql**.

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

Then start **mysql** , **apache2**.

**Note** : You have to reinstall all database to work with.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a password for user rishi before you can connect to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect as root first. The root password can be found in your home directory as some sort of hidden file or in the MySQL install log.

When you have the password type:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

Answer (score 0):

To the the version , you should give like this

```
mysql --version
```